# Why is Logcat output in Android studio different in two similar cases?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Why is the output different in the below cases?

```
   public void onResponse(Call call, Response response){

      //first line...
      Log.i("Body", "" + (response.body().toString()));

     String mMessage = response.body().string();
      //second line
      Log.i("Message", "" + mMessage);

    }
```

I got two different Logcat output

> I/Body: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@387ce26
>   I/Message{"name":"mohamed3@gmail.com","email":"mohamed3@gmail.com","type":"1","msg":"sucessfully"}

is there any explanation for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.body().toString()` is a *reference* to an `instanceof` `String` -

while `response.body().string()` is obtaining it's `String` value.